# Cannot specify multiple rpath in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, linker

I would like to specify in the Miscellaneous section of GCC C++ Linker multiple rpaths.

Linker Flags:

`-Wl,-rpath=/home/cri/Libs1, -Wl,-rpath=/home/cri/Libs2`

For one it's working, but when I add the second one I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libmylib.so] Error 1
```

Could I get please some help on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to drop the comma between the two flags (and I use it without equal symbols):

```
-Wl,-rpath /home/cri/Libs1 -Wl,-rpath /home/cri/Libs2
```

That should work.

Comment: Can I user -Wl,-rpath,lib1:lib2?